# GhostScript output to file

Tags: ghostscript

I use GhostScript to check for corrupt pdf files using the following command:

```
gswin64c.exe -o nul -sDEVICE=nullpage input.pdf
```

and I get the following output on the screen:

```
Processing pages 1 to 2.
Page 1
  *****Error reading a content stream. The page may not be incomplete.
Page 2
  *****Warning: File has insufficient data for an image.

  *****This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
```

This information is exactly what I need but I need this output in a text file as I will have to process a large number of files.

I tried to use the following command:

```
gswin64c.exe -o outputfile.txt -sDEVICE=txtwrite input.pdf
```

but the outputfile is empty.

How can I output these information into the file?

Answer (score 2):

try redirecting [stdout and stderr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) to files

eg.

```
gswin64c.exe -o nul -sDEVICE=nullpage input.pdf > output.txt 2> errors.txt
```

Comment: Thank you - it is exactly what I needed. Is there an easy way to add a file name to the stdout and stderr?

Comment: depends how you get the input filenames, try using the same mechanism you use to decide which file to process, but append a .txt or .err to it.